# Плагин для PyCharm для подсветки областей видимости

Tags: python, pycharm, плагин, color

Помню был плагин для подсветки областей видимости в PyCharm. Не цветовое выделение скобочек и т.п., а цветовое выделение именно боковой линии, идущей вдоль области видимости. Может кто помнит название или знает аналоги? В качестве примера прилагаю нарисованный ручками пример, как выглядела та подсветка:

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 4):

На ум приходит только [Indent Rainbow](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13308-indent-rainbow).

Сам им пользуюсь. :)